# How to add a pretrained ML Core model to Flutter app?

Tags: swift, flutter, mlmodel

I have a pretrained .mlmodel file, but when I add to my Runner, I can't access it from AppDelegate.swift. I have my app written in Flutter. Also it works with a different project written in Swift.

[image]